# Solving $x^{2n} = \frac{1}{2^n}$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms, exponential-function, branch-cuts

What is the principle behind solving for a variable that is raised to another variable?  I came across this problem doing infinite sums: I had to solve the equation

$$x^{2n} = \frac{1}{2^n}$$

for $x$. I posed the question in the online forum and the TA said the answer is

$$x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

I don't see how he got there.  If someone could explain how to get from one to the other, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Please format your question better. Is it $x^2 n$ or $x^{2n}$?

Comment: Similarly, is it $\frac{1}{2}n$, $\frac{1}{2n}$ or $\frac{1}{2^n}$?

Comment: It looks like x^(2n)=1/(2n).

Answer (score 6):

$x^{2n}=(x^2)^n=\frac{1}{2^n}$. So if $n\neq 0$, for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ you have $x^2=\frac{1}{2}$ then $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: what is if $$n=0$$?

Comment: That is usually a special case.

Comment: Alternatively
$$x^{2n}=\frac{1}{2^n}=\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n=\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^\frac{2n}{2}=\bigg(\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{2n}=\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^{2n}\implies\text{ yada yada yada}$$

Comment: How would you solve for x if the question had been $ x^2n=1/2n $?

Answer (score 3):

To solve an expression like $x^{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}$ for $x$, you need to use logarithms. As was quite rightly pointed out, if $n\neq 0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R},$ then

$$(x^2)^n=\frac{1}{2^n}\Rightarrow x^2=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

If $n=0$, then we have a blow-up singularity. Hence we will need to travel in an arbitrarily small circuit around the singularity (hence this extra term).

Taking logarithms of both sides and using the log power rule gives
$$
2n\ln(x)=2\pi ik+\ln(\frac{1}{2n}),~k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Travelling in an anticlockwise traversal along a simple closed curve around the origin gives the extra $2\pi ik$ term (the logarithm is given by $2\pi k$ multiplied by $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, with $k$ the winding number). . Dividing both sides by $2n$ gives
$$
\ln(x)=\frac{\pi ik}{n}+\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{2n})}{2n},~k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Take the exponential function of both sides, and you have an expression for $x$.

Comment: Your reputation at this moment corresponds to the first four digits of $\pi$ (rounded to 3dp)!

Comment: So it does! Fancy that!

Comment: Better take a screenshot before it changes :)

Comment: Done that already!

Comment: can you tell me why you added this 2πik

Comment: It is related to the fact that there is a singularity at the origin, and we travel in an arbitrarily small circuit around the origin. It is a logarithmic branch point so the circuit is represented by $2\pi i$ multiplied by the winding number (in this case, $k$). I have added this to my answer.